# C# Hjson returns null after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, app-config, hjson

I have a hjson file like this that I want to deserialize and work with:

```
{
"TestConfig": {
  "SecondConfig": {
    "ConnectionString": "Integrated Security = true; Data Source = dataPseudo; Initial Catalog = catalogPseudo; Connect Timeout = 180",
    "SpecificationPseudo": "pseudo",
    "NumberOfHintsPseudo": 300
  },

  "ThirdConfig": "pseudo"
}... // more hjson coming here.
```

I load it with the HjsonValue.Load method like this:

```
private static Foo convertJson()
{
var loadedValue = HjsonValue.Load("hjsonFile.hjson").ToString();
return new JsonSerializer<Foo>().DeserializeFromString(loadedValue);
// another failed method: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(loadedValue);
// A third failed method: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Foo>>(loadedValue);
}
```

I think my problem is in the 2 c#-coded lines, but can't figure what. Am I deserializing wrong or what seems to be the problem? I suspect that it's because it is a nested json, but can't find a way to deserialize it. Trying to use dictionary as it is a answer in a other stack-question, but it didn't work for me.

Note: The first and second tried return method don't return any errors, but they just return a nullreferenceexception since "SecondConfig" and "ThirdConfig" both are null..

**Update** (with help from er-sho): removed the "root"-element from the hjson (TestConfig), which solved the problem.

Comment: Is anything special in your json that you used `Hjson` instead on `json` only?

Comment: Nothing but the ability to comment the json. That shouldn't be the problem though, since it loads the file correctly.

Comment: could you please show the value in `loadedValue`?

Comment: Yes, question is updated with the value.

Comment: It just converts from hjson to json - removing the comments.

Comment: so do you want your json can be deserialized with `newtonsoft` right?

Comment: Yes, well I want to be able to use the elements "SecondConfig" and "ThirdConfig", which are both null even though they obviously have a value in json.

Comment: So how much those elements? its only 2 that you said above or may be undetermined.

Comment: just 2, The rest of the json/hjson has no value for this method. So only SecondConfig and ThirdConfig..

Comment: Try these classes => `public class SecondConfig
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationPseudo { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfHintsPseudo { get; set; }
}

public class TestConfiguration
{
    public SecondConfig SecondConfig { get; set; }
    public string ThirdConfig { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public TestConfiguration TestConfiguration { get; set; }
}`

Comment: And deserialize it like => `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(loadedValue);`

Comment: Ah! You lead me in the right direction! I removed the "TestConfig" from the hjson since it's root and the class that I am working with. This solved the problem and now it returns the correct values. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing "TestConfig" from the hjson fixed it, since it's root and the class I am working with.